Camera tracking multiple drone shots of the same place with only one scene setup
I have recorded some drone footage of a small area in my hometown for a archviz project. I would like to add different CGI buildings into four different shots, each with a different viewing angle. I have researched Motion Tracking in Blender intensively, considered all camera settings and I also undistorted the footage before tracking. My solve error is less than 0.2px but I just can't manage to set up my scene so that the buildings are placed correctly in each of the four shots. To achieve my goal, I have to duplicate the buildings for each shot and move them manually to the correct position, which is super tedious and time consuming.
Is it theoretically possible to include several buildings in different drone shots without having to manually rearrange the buildings again and again? Or are the errors caused by tracking, camera settings, lens distortion etc. simply too great in such a large scale? I'm really a little lost, thanks in advance for any answers!

everyone's scared of your question.
I've honestly never tried more than one clip at a time in motion tracking, so I'd have no clue how to help you.   I'd guess you could just add one camera for each shot, and track them separately.  Then you could align each one in the viewport?

Thanks for your answer! Yep, I'm afraid it's a bit of a tricky issue  I have tracked each shot individually and also adjusted my cameras manually. But still, I just can't avoid repositioning all my objects by hand. I wish I knew a better workflow for this.

Ah yeah man, that stinks.  Well, best of luck to you!
